# Why are my icon decorators not being found in InitializeShapeFields when they positioned outside my shape?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, dsl

I have created a custom image field that performs an event on double click, and I'm replacing the icon in InitializeShapeFields as the docs say.

When I place the icon inside the shape (InnerMiddleRight) I can double click on it, but when I place it outside (OuterTopRight), the decorator isn't found in InitializeShapeFields() and I can't double click it.  when I click on it it highlights both the parent shape and decorator, so it is recognizing the link.

Am I missing something with regards to interaction events on decorators?

```
 protected override void InitializeShapeFields(IList<ShapeField> shapeFields)
    {
        base.InitializeShapeFields(shapeFields);           

        ShapeField editCodeField = shapeFields.FirstOrDefault(f => f.Name == "EditCodeDecorator");

        if (editCodeField == null)
            return;

        shapeFields.Remove(editCodeField);

        ImageField editCodeImage = new ShowCodeImageField("EditCodeDecorator")
        {
            DefaultImage = ImageHelper.GetImage(
                PFlowDomainModel.SingletonResourceManager.GetObject("BaseShapeEditCodeDecoratorDefaultImage"))
        };
        shapeFields.Add(editCodeImage);
    }

internal class ShowCodeImageField : ImageField
{
    public static BuildCodeEvent InteractionEvents = new BuildCodeEvent();

    public ShowCodeImageField(string fieldName) : base(fieldName)
    {
    }

    public ShowCodeImageField(string fieldName, Image image) : base(fieldName, image)
    {
    }

    public override void OnDoubleClick(DiagramPointEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnDoubleClick(e);

        BaseShape shapeHit = e.HitDiagramItem.Shape as BaseShape;

        if (shapeHit != null)
        {
            InteractionEvents.OnRegisterFileBuildEvent(shapeHit);

            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I've solved part of the problem... I've followed the same strategy as above but in InitializeDecorators() find decorated with shape remove add new one... first issue is trying to get the old decorators properties to rebuild the new one without hard coding the properties, and second is when I double click the test doesn't get the shape...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I solved my problem after some poking around in the generated code and observing some of the properties of objects.

This gave it away in the generate code:

```
/// <summary>
    /// Initialize the collection of decorators associated with this shape type.  This method also
    /// creates shape fields for outer decorators, because these are not part of the shape fields collection
    /// associated with the shape, so they must be created here rather than in InitializeShapeFields.
    /// </summary>
```

So to get double clicking on an icon decorator outside of your shape you need to replace the decorator in InitialiseDecorators() with a new one that has the custom image field, and then don't use hit e.HitDiagramItem.Shape.

Here is my solution:

```
protected override void InitializeDecorators(IList<ShapeField> shapeFields, IList<Decorator> decorators)
    {
        base.InitializeDecorators(shapeFields, decorators);

        var oldDecorator = decorators.FirstOrDefault(d => d.Field.Name == "EditCodeDecorator");            

        if (oldDecorator == null)
            return;

        decorators.Remove(oldDecorator);

        ImageField editCodeImageField = new ShowCodeImageField("EditCodeDecorator")
        {
            DefaultImage = ImageHelper.GetImage(
                PFlowDomainModel.SingletonResourceManager.GetObject("BaseShapeEditCodeDecoratorDefaultImage"))
        };

        var newDecorator = new ShapeDecorator(editCodeImageField, ShapeDecoratorPosition.OuterTopRight, new PointD(-0.1, -0.1));
        decorators.Add(newDecorator);
    }

public override void OnDoubleClick(DiagramPointEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnDoubleClick(e);

        var decoratorHostShape = e.HitDiagramItem.RepresentedElements.Cast<DecoratorHostShape>().First();

        var shape = decoratorHostShape.ParentShape;         

        if (shape != null)
        {
            InteractionEvents.OnRegisterFileBuildEvent(shape);

            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
```

Hope this can help someone out there, and if anyone knows a better way please let me know below...